# Hyperledger fabric v1.0 local environment setup containing 4 peers to deal with 4 applications running on different servers

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to implement a demo blockchain network using **Hyperlegdger Fabric v1.0**. I have followed the [getting started](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) and everything going fine so far. 
I could also be able to setup the sample network by following [Building Your First Network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html).

But still I am not getting clarity to meet my requirement mentioned below

I have 4 applications running on 4 different weblogic servers and asset created from 1 application should be shared among the other three applications.

> Eg:
>
> - **App1** creating **Asset1** of **quantity 100**
> - By running the chaincode I need to share **Asset1** among other 3 applications with the ratio ***App2:App3:App4 = 20:40:30***

Prviously I was trying out the same using Hyperledger fabric v0.6 service provided by [IBM Bluemix](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/) and now only upgrading to V1.0 by doing the [local environment setup](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html).

In the Sample network there available *2 organisations with 2 peers each*. In my case I need to setup ***4 peers, one for each application*** and I need some suggestions for the below points.

1. How to create 4 peers for this requirement? will it need to setup peers in different machine where each server is running or can I setup the 4 peers in same machine?
2. Can I customise this 2 organisation with 2 peers model to 4 organisation 1 peer moderl to deal with each application?

Someone please clarify these and give your valuable suggestions to meet this requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to create 4 peers for this requirement? will it need to setup
>   peers in different machine where each server is running or can I setup
>   the 4 peers in same machine?

You can just extend the docker-compose file to have more peers.
In case you want to setup peers on different machines you can use [this script](https://github.com/yacovm/fabricDeployment) if you have VMs you want to use as peers and a VM to be used as an orderer.

> Can I customise this 2 organisation with 2 peers model to 4
>   organisation 1 peer moderl to deal with each application?

You need to extend the [configtx.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/first-network/configtx.yaml) file to have more organizations, 
and then also update the [crypto-config.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/first-network/crypto-config.yaml) accordingly

Comment: Big thanks for the script. Yes now I am trying in that way, so I am on the right track :)